# Artefacts analysis for Microsoft Photos app: mapping of tables in MediaDb.v1.sqlite

Tags: windows, photo, computer-forensics

I'm trying to understand artefacts left by Microsoft Photos app better and want to check how to interpret the mapping of tables found in `~\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\MediaDb.v1.sqlite` files. My problem is that I can see almost 128 tables contained in that but since there seems to be no unique id, I find it hard to map which table's id/row correspond to which image in the Photos app, making it hard to understand what information corresponds to what image.

I understand this might not be the best platform for this question but any kind of help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)